# Is there a program that will monitor for new startup/autorun programs and alert me as they are installed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, malware

Programs are constantly gumming up my windows-10 system by installing crud that I don't want as startup programs, "services", and scheduled tasks.

The excellent [*Autoruns* utility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) lets me see the crud ***after the fact***.

What I want is a program that ***monitors* for new startup stuff** and ***alerts* me as it attempts to be installed**. So that it can be blocked or immediately removed.

Google searches for "windows", plus terms like "startup" or "autorun", etc. yield a whole lot of results, none of which seem to apply.

Is there a trustworthy tool that does this?

Comment: I wondered the same and couldn't found anything good. I'm tempting of attempting to write it myself :D

Comment: @Alejandro, that's a thought.  It could be as simple as polling some folders and registry keys, maybe?  Bonus if it also triggered off any install hooks that windows may have...

Comment: Pooling will certainly do, my only doubt being the timing interval and the disk load it imposses. Windows has no concept of "install", but it has some hooks for monitor file changes, and I think it also has for registry changes, that's a much better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of Startup monitoring applications available, some better and some worse... (but I doubt anything as complete - with all types of startups - as Autoruns.)

[**SterJo Startup Patrol**](http://www.sterjosoft.com/startup-patrol.html) is a nice and polished one. (But the installer might install Adware, so be aware, or use the portable version which doesn't do that.)

Another popular software that has this functionality is [**WinPatrol**](http://www.winpatrol.com/). It might be an overkill since it does more stuff.

Comment: Thanks, trying both -- though WinPatrol sure doesn't make it easy to tell the various editions and programs apart.